# Is there a way to bring in vectors from an AutoCAD file without them being filled?

Tags: import

I come to Blender from the CAD world.  I am teaching Blender to 12 students.  We are working on a scene that happens in Charleston Harbor in 1862.  I found an old chart and scaled it to full size using AutoCAD.  Then I traced it making closed polylines.  I can bring it into Blender as an FBX, but those closed shapes come in looking like this image:
[image]

I want to make a landscape using the shapes I created, giving it height.  Do any of you know how I might un-fill the shapes?

Comment: Blender imports what is there, so this issue is most likely on the other side. Empty faces may not be supported in the export filetype you are using as well. Just a thought, but why don't you model it in Blender?

Comment: I did not know how to measure and trace in Blender.  I've used AutoCAD for years as well as Inventor.  In the future I will try tracing in Blender instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a plug-in for importing DXF files that gives  you a lot more options than FBX and it looks like it imports linework as paths instead of meshes.
[image]

Comment: @Randy Van Nostrand Don't edit answers for this, comment it

Comment: Thanks for this idea.  I went to the download section in the link provided and extracted the file folder.  I don't know where to put the stuff I extracted.  I went to the Blender Foundation folder and putt all of it there.  I don't see an option for AutoCAD DXF in the import menu, even when I click the box in Add-ons.  Where did I go wrong?  Thanks John Burrill and Bithur.

Comment: I think if you just unpack it into: <i> \Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.73\scripts\addons\ </i>
-and restart blender it will work.

Comment: John, I am using Blender 2.72 in my class.  I can't seem to get the plugin to work.  In the notes under that Add-on ist says "Warning, Under construction!  Visit Wiki for details.  I'm lost.

Comment: Try the download link on this page:
https://bitbucket.org/treyerl/io_import_scene_dxf/overview

Comment: Ok.  I've installed the new dxf importer but now I get the message:  "Multiple addons using the same name found!
Likely a problem with the script search path.
(see console for details)"  Can you tell me how to delete the old dxf converter?

Comment: Now when I try the DXF import function it does not work.  I get a scene list entry but nothing shows in the 3D window.  The script does not work.

Comment: try disabling the other dxf add-on.  If that doesn't work, then close blender, delete the old dxf add-on python file from the addons folder and restart Blender.